# How to get a screen shot of a web page from a url

Tags: screenshot

Im trying to figure out how to let a user enter a website or link on my webpage and then based on that url I would like to display a screenshot of that link sort of similar to when you post a video link from youtube on face book it grabs a small image.  Ive seen some services but Id rather implement something myself on my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used programs like webkit2png in the past, but it's mac-only.  I have never used it but this looks like a more generic linux equivalent:

http://khtml2png.sourceforge.net/

I presume your server is running some flavor of linux; you might have to jump through some hoops to install Qt and ImageMagick if you don't have them already or if you are on a shared server.

For the record, although it says that it can't "scale the output image" in the newer versions of this library, that's a very straightforward operation you can apply with many other libraries/programs.

Comment: I shouldve mentioned that Im running windows server 2008 r2 sp-something something. Im not really trying to create screen shots but I would like to have one appear when some one posts a weblink similar to how facebook or linkedIn do when you post a weblink.